# Python: How to get real depth from disparity map

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, distance, depth

I am a complete beginner I am trying to obtain real depth map from left and right image. I've used OpenCV to get the disparity map via block matching as you can see in the code bellow.

```
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv
import sys
import numpy as np

def getDisparity(imgLeft, imgRight, method="BM"):

gray_left = cv2.cvtColor(imgLeft, cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)
gray_right = cv2.cvtColor(imgRight, cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)
print gray_left.shape
c, r = gray_left.shape
if method == "BM":
    sbm = cv.CreateStereoBMState()
    disparity = cv.CreateMat(c, r, cv.CV_32F)
    sbm.SADWindowSize = 11
    sbm.preFilterType = 1
    sbm.preFilterSize = 5
    sbm.preFilterCap = 61
    sbm.minDisparity = -50
    sbm.numberOfDisparities = 112
    sbm.textureThreshold = 507
    sbm.uniquenessRatio= 0
    sbm.speckleRange = 8
    sbm.speckleWindowSize = 0

    gray_left = cv.fromarray(gray_left)
    gray_right = cv.fromarray(gray_right)

    cv.FindStereoCorrespondenceBM(gray_left, gray_right, disparity, sbm)
    disparity_visual = cv.CreateMat(c, r, cv.CV_8U)
    cv.Normalize(disparity, disparity_visual, 0, 255, cv.CV_MINMAX)
    disparity_visual = np.array(disparity_visual)

elif method == "SGBM":
    sbm = cv2.StereoSGBM()
    sbm.SADWindowSize = 9;
    sbm.numberOfDisparities = 0;
    sbm.preFilterCap = 63;
    sbm.minDisparity = -21;
    sbm.uniquenessRatio = 7;
    sbm.speckleWindowSize = 0;
    sbm.speckleRange = 8;
    sbm.disp12MaxDiff = 1;
    sbm.fullDP = False;

    disparity = sbm.compute(gray_left, gray_right)
    disparity_visual = cv2.normalize(disparity, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.cv.CV_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.cv.CV_8U)

return disparity_visual

imgLeft = cv2.imread('1.png')
imgRight = cv2.imread('2.png')
try:
    method = "BM"
except IndexError:
    method = "BM"

disparity = getDisparity(imgLeft, imgRight, method)
cv2.imshow("disparity", disparity)
#cv2.imshow("left", imgLeft)
#cv2.imshow("right", imgRight)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

My question is what is the easiest way to obtain real depth map (distance) from disparity using python?

Answer (score 2):

In order to calculate depth for stereo, you need to know the translation and rotation between the cameras.  If you have that, you can take each disparity value and use triangulation to calculate the depth for that 3D point.

I recommend reading http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/hzbook/
for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your cameras are calibrated, the images rectified, you can use the formula provided by [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d53/tutorial_py_depthmap.html) which is:

```
disparity = Baseline * focal-lens / depth
```

So,

```
depth = Baseline * focal-lens / disparity
```